# Raspberry не видит USB камеру

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, камера

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла необходимость получать фото с usb камеры, подключенной к малине, в питоне. Но дело в том, что стандартная библиотека PiCamera не видит камеру, хотя она подключена правильно, и мне даже удалось получить с нее изображение с помощью luvcview. В чем проблема?
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/cammm.py", line 4, in <module>
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 431, 
in __init__
self._init_camera(camera_num, stereo_mode, stereo_decimate)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 460, 
 in _init_camera
 "Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' "
 picamera.exc.PiCameraError: Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi- 
 config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.
```

Код:

```
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.start_preview()
# Camera warm-up time
sleep(2)
camera.capture('foo.jpg')
```

Comment: а sudo raspi-config запускали? проверяли

Comment: само собой проверял

Comment: думаю, что стандартная библиотека рассчитывает на стандартную камеру для raspberry, а не произвольную, подключенную в usb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать захватить картинку через pygame:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera

pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480))
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img,"filename.jpg")
```